# how to release flutter app to google play?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-build, flutter-release

I want to release an flutter app for Google play store and I checked every step of in Instruction page of flutter, but every time I got this error:

```
* What went wrong:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

**update:** I waw wrong with naming key file :) it was key.propertis an 'e' has been left

Comment: Did you add the keystore file in the specified path?

Comment: yes I added but its not working

Comment: Path may be wrong, could you please explain little bit more about where you added the file and how you defined the store file location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the `signingConfig` for release inside your `android/app/build.gradle` file. It should look like this:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias 'keyAlias'
        keyPassword 'keyPassword'
        storeFile file('storeLocation')
        storePassword 'storePassword'
    }
}
```

This should be put inside the `android` section.

Comment: no I inlcude it like this:
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

Comment: And what is keystoreProperties? Are you sure that it is filled with `storeFile` for example? Without it, your code would set `storeFile` to null and probably also causing this error.